# Instagram stories graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I making a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/17841XXXXXXXXX/stories
I am getting the following error

"Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxx989027xxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException"

Please help to sort this out and get the url of the IG stories

Comment: Assuming that is a valid IG user ID, then you probably lack the necessary permissions. Have you read the documentation to figure out which permission(s) the endpoint in question actually requires?

Comment: Is the ID your own account? Where did you get ID from?

Comment: yes it is my own account

Comment: @CBroe can you please tell me how do i get the permissions?

Comment: You ask for them during login, as explained in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started